# Is these many-to-many relations for more than two tables are good?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm a newbie in database design.

Can anybody look at this design:

[image]

- Initially I created these tables - m2m relation first. It was simple:

  - `students`
  - `contacts`
  - `contact_types`
- But new table `teachers` was added into database after that.
- ...and each `teacher` may have `contact` too.
- I just added new column into `contacts` "junction" table.

  - But I don't like this design, because there are empty values in columns of `teacher_id` and `student_id` columns.
- Is there better way to create many-to-many relations for that situation?
- **Main goal is to get ability of adding multiple contacts for one `student`/`teacher`**.

---

The former variant of my design, but I don't know if it is optimal or not.

[image: old schema]

Comment: What do you wish?

Comment: I wouldn't even have a contacts table at all. Just add the contact type and value on each of student and teacher table, cleaner. with a FK to contact type

Comment: If the goal is to allow multiple contacts... I will add an answer

Comment: @JorgeCampos Exactly!

Comment: There was a mistake in image. Now it is correct. Sorry...

Comment: Added an answer, that way you will have all contacts in one place and each link (student/teacher) separated correctly into its own table.

Answer (score 1):

To allow your design to be M:M you need something like this:

```
table teacher { id, .... }
table student { id, ...}
table contact { id, typeId, value }
table contactType {id, ....}
table contact_teacher {contactId, teacherId}
table contact_student {contactId, studentId}
```

Then you have your M:M relationship between `student` and `contact` and `teacher` and `contact`

Comment: Thank you, Jorge! It is what I wanted from the start. But it seems some confusing to me, because there are two junction tables to one target table and they have identical structure. It is optimal?

Comment: It really is a matter of preference. To answer your question, yes it is optimal if you properly add indexes to it. Your model to me is already ok, as long as it is properly indexed and you know how to build a query to get the data you want. This one is best optimal in the sense of each data is within its own space, so you don't query student if you need teachers and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to create a many to many relationship between teachers and contacts is to create a "joining table"  that table would look like this:

```
 contactteacher table

 name      type
 id        int - auto increment 
 teacherid int
 contactid int
```

I like to call the tables by the things they join ordered alphabetically that is why I suggest the name contactteacher

There might be additional information for contact -- like where you met someone or when you met them.

There could also be meta data in the table -- when the record was created when it was edited, who created it -- etc.

Comment: @dai -- they are asking how to make m:m between teacher and contact.

Comment: @dai -- they call the table contacts -- which makes it sound like it contacts between people but actually this is a table that would be called "people" in most DBs -- each row can be a person.  Some are students some are teachers.

Comment: Main idea is to add ability to add various communication ways ("contacts") to students and teachers. Types of contacts are common for each other. I'd decided to create two junction tables first. But is it good to create two identical tables to one target table?

Comment: @MaxDubrovin -- Sure if they are joining to different tables it is fine.  Don't worry about having an extra table... it is not a lot of extra over head compared to how complicated combining table together that should be combined would require.